# Do YOU need to touch your opponents with Your Power is Mine?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, beast-the-primordial

This is a power question about Insatiables. The text of "Your Power Is Mine" goes:

> An Insatiable can steal an Atavism or Nightmare from a Beast by touching
>   her opponent and spending a point of Satiety.

If a Beast has grappled an Insatiable, can the Insatiable then use this power without "moving"—in other words, without making an attack roll? Or does it have to manage to get control of the grapple and then use the power via an active action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer on page 165 of the *Beast: the Primordial* core book. That's where you can find the rules both for **Grappling** and for **Touching an Opponent**. One does have to make a Dexterity + Brawl roll to deliver an attack via touch. (It mentions Fist of Nightmares explicitly, but there doesn't seem to be a reason to make exceptions here.) If you're in a grapple and succeed, you'll be able to Break Free or Hold your opponent to make that attack more easily delivered.

After that, you'll make the opposed Satiety + Manipulation roll versus the
Beast’s Satiety + Lair that "Your Power Is Mine" requires.

It seems needful to also mention that Insatiables are not a PC splat; they're an adversary from the *Night Horrors: Conquering Heroes* book. If you're acting on the Insatiable's behalf, you might decide that your NPC can deliver the attack through skin contact alone. But if you want to follow the rules, there they are.